# Accessing elements inside an IFrame srcdoc using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So, I'm trying to get an element inside of an iframe srcdoc using jQuery/javascript, and say, attach a click handler. e.g..

```
<iframe id="iframe" srcdoc="<html><head></head><body><input type="button" id="button" /></body></html>"></iframe>
```

The following code does not work:

```
$("#iframe").find("#button").on("click", function{ alert('clicked'); });
```

Nor does using $("#iframe").contents() or several other methods.

How can I attach event handlers to elements inside an Iframe srcdoc?

Comment: I believe jQuery's `.contents()` function will grab the HTML inside an iFrame's `srcdoc` attribute just as it would if that HTML were nested inside of the tags. You will be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe (perhaps rendering this question a duplicate?)

Comment: also, your JS is a bit malformed. You'll need to append `()` after `function` in your callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS to handle click :

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").find("#button").click(function() {alert('clicked')});
```

HTML changes :

```
<iframe id="iframe" srcdoc="<html><head></head><body><input type='button' id='button' /></body></html>"></iframe>
```

EDIT: load iframe using JS :

```
$("#container").append($("<iframe />").attr({"srcdoc":"<html><head></head><body><input type='button' id='button' /></body></html>", "id":"iframe" })); 

$("#iframe").load( function() {
    $("#iframe").contents().find("body").find("#button").click(
        function () {alert('clicked')}
    );
});
```

working Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/hufrmcLt/

EDIT : http://jsfiddle.net/hufrmcLt/1/

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Is it because of the way I'm appending the container element to the dom, then immediately attaching event handlers?

Comment: `        $(".container").append($("<iframe />").attr({"srcdoc":"<html><head></head><body><input type='button' id='button' /></body></html>",
                                                         "id":"iframe"
                                                        }));

        $("#iframe").contents().find("body").find("#button").click(function () {
            alert('clicked');
        });`

Comment: The way you are appending iframe is the issue, when the iframe is not appended the event is trying to get bind to button(it's actually not there in body)

Comment: So is it a timing issue? What's a better way to accomplish this?